# Escaping spaces in filename is not working inside script

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

At the command line, this `cat` works as expected:

```
cat /home/me/path\ with\ spaces/to/file
```

But if I put it in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="$1" 
cat $FILE # cat "$FILE" gives same result
```

and call the script with `./script.sh "/home/me/path\ with\ spaces/to/file"`, I get:

```
cat: /home/me/path\ with\ spaces/to/file: No such file or directory
```

Note the escape quotes, which should be in the right places.

What gives?

Comment: You have the quotes in the wrong place: `file=$1` (no quotes necessary, though it doesn't hurt to have some), but more importantly: `cat "$file"` (here quotes are mandatory!). And then call your script as: either `./script.sh /home/me/path\ with\ spaces/to/file` with no quotes, since the spaces are escaped or `./script.sh "/home/me/path with spaces/to/file"` with quotes but no escaping of the spaces.

Comment: add `set -vx` hear the top of the script to enable shell debug/trace mode. You will then see what values are being passed around. If you dbl-quote a string, then you don't need to escape the spaces inside the string.

Comment: Yep, it was double-escaped. Thanks guys for the tips, appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use double quotes to prevent word splitting:

```
cat "$FILE"
```

As an aside, upper case variable names should be reserved for shell internal variables, so you should change `FILE` to `file`.

If you are quoting the argument to your script (which is a good idea), then the file name doesn't need backslashes:

```
./script.sh "/home/me/path with spaces/to/file"
```

Comment: It was double-escaped. Thank you Tom, for the naming tip too.